# During Djikstra algorithm when can the shortest path to a vertex u that is just being added to the reached set S contain vertices outside S

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I am reading through Introduction to Algorithms by T.H.Cormen and I having a hard time understanding a point from the Djikstra algorithm correctness proof. Basically we have this image
[image]

With the following explanation:

> The proof of Theorem 22.6. Vertex u is selected to be added into set S in line 7 of
> DIJKSTRA. Vertex y is the first vertex on a shortest path from the source s to vertex u that is not in
> set S, and x in S is y's predecessor on that shortest path. The subpath from y to u may or may not
> re-enter set S.

What I find difficult to understand is how come the shortest path exit and then reenter S. If U's predecessor in S (let's say z) is from S then it's minimal distance is reached but how can that be if the minimal path to this z exits S?

Moreover how could u.d be smaller than y.d in the first place? I was expecting this to be given as a contradiction to reach the conclusion that y = u but is seems like that is not the case. It concludes that u.d = y.d but not that u = y. Does this mean this can only happen when weights are 0?

An example where such a case happens would greatly help me.

Comment: I agree with your thoughts: if $y$ is on a shortest path to $u$, then $y$ should be added before $u$ unless the path from $y$ to $u$ has length 0. So it's either a contradiction proof or a situation that can only happen when some edge weights are 0. Does the correctness proof work if you interpret it that way?

Comment: Dijkstra's algorithm has several variants depending on exactly what problem you are trying to solve, so it is hard to answer this question without known which variant your book is trying to prove. Is it the most common variant, where you fix a starting node $s$ and then label every node $n$ with the minimal length of a path from $s$ to $n$? (This probably boils down to "what is $S$?").

Comment: Quote from the book - ""Instead, Dijkstra's algorithm maintains a set S of vertices whose final shortest-
path weights from the source s have already been determined. The algorithm repeatedly selects the vertex u from V - S with the minimum shortest-path estimate,
adds u into S, and relaxes all edges leaving u.